# Why is serverSelected null?

Tags: c#, exception

### View Model

```
string _serverSelected;
        public string serverSelected
        {
            get { return _serverSelected; }
            set
            {
                if (_serverSelected != value)
                    _serverSelected = value;

                RaisePropertyChanged("serverSelected");              
            }
        }

        public BackUpViewModel()
        {

             BackUpContext servObj = new BackUpContext();                      
            _DBNameList = servObj.GetDBNames(serverSelected);
        }
```

### DAL

```
public List<string> GetDBNames(string sqlServerName)
        {
    List<string> lstDBName = new List<string>();         


                SqlConnectionStringBuilder connection = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
                connection.DataSource = sqlServerName;
                connection.IntegratedSecurity = true;
                String strCon = connection.ToString();
                SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(strCon);
                sqlConn.Open();

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from sys.databases", sqlConn);
                SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    lstDBName.Add(dr[0].ToString());
                }
                sqlConn.Close();


                return lstDBName;
}
```

### APP.config

```js
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>        

    <add name="CostAllocationEntities2" connectionString="Data Source=pc210090\SQLExpress;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=password1$" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    </connectionStrings>  

  <appSettings>

    <add key="ServerName1" value="PC210090\SQLEXPRESS"/>
    <add key="ServerName2" value="s2"/>
    <add key="ServerName3" value="s3"/>    
    <add key="BackupDestinationPath" value="D:\BackUpDatabase\"/>
    <add key="RestoreDestinationPath" value="D:\RestoreDatabase\"/>  

  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

`_DBNameList = servObj.GetDBNames(serverSelected);`
 this serverSelected is always passing as null which is not allowing my code to build and i am not able to select server from server list because of this.

Comment: `_DBNameList = servObj.GetDBNames(_serverSelected);` ??

Comment: where are you setting the value for `_serverSelected `?

Comment: I have two combo boxes, one for server list & second for the data bases that should be populated based on the above server Selected.

Comment: ViewModel: 
_ServerNameList = servObj.GetServer("ServerName");            
 _DBNameList = servObj.GetDBNames(serverSelected);            
  serverCommand = new RelayCommand(fetchServer);
 public void fetchServer(object server)
        {
            serverSelected = server.ToString();          
            
        }

Comment: DAL for server combo box population :

public List<string> GetServer(string server)
        {
            var keys = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Keys;
            return keys.Cast<object>()
                       .Where(key => key.ToString().ToLower()
                       .Contains(server.ToLower()))
                       .Select(key => ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get(key.ToString())).ToList();
        }

Comment: @NagarajS No. That didn't help.

Comment: @AmanJain you should debug your `_serverSelected` You can easily identify if any exceptioin